# Limit of a series defined by a nonlinear recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I have a nonlinear recurrence relation as follows, $$x_{t+1}=x_t^a+b$$ where $a,b\in (0,1)$ and $x_0>1$.

I have a rough idea of how to find the limit of this relation (correct me if I'm wrong). First I will prove the monotonicity (2 cases arise, increasing and decreasing depending on the values of $a$ and $b$). Second, I need to prove that it is bounded (I'm still stuck here). If the second step is done, I can find the fixed point and that will be the limit of this relation.

The real problem is I have to **find the limit of this series**: $$\sum^{k}_{i=0}\beta^{k-i}x_{i}$$

where $\beta \in (0,1)$. As of now I have no idea how to proceed. Since the limit of $\{x_t\}$ exists (although I'm still struggling to prove its existence), I assume the limit of the above series also exist.

I have consulted a couple of other posts related to this issues but found out that they are generally very specific and mostly deal with quadratic relations, which obviously do not apply to my case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the limit of the series as $k$ increases without bound exists only if the $x_i$ approach zero.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics ah sorry, I forgot to mention the condition on $\beta<1$. Does it change anything if I add the condition?